# can't launch first example for Cucumber+javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, cucumber

I tried to launch first example from official documentation here 
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/nodejs_example.md

- I used Windows 7x64 bit , node.js 6.11
- I tried the following commands and got the same result

*

```
node_modules/cucumber/bin/cucumber.js autotests/cucumber-test/features/documentation.feature
node_modules\cucumber\bin\cucumber.js autotests\cucumber-test\features\documentation.feature
cucumber autotests\cucumber-test\features\documentation.feature
cucumber-js autotests\cucumber-test\features\documentation.feature
```

*

and I got the following error

```
cucumber.js:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^
    SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
        at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
        at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
        at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
        at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
        at getDefinitions (<path>\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\cli\profiles_loader.js:8:23)
```

I also tried to downgrade to cucumber 1.3.3 but it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Please try below command:

node_modules\cucumber\bin\cucumber.js.cmd  autotests\cucumber-test\features\documentation.feature

Comment: I have  only cucumber.js  file  into node_modules\cucumber\bin

Answer (score 0):

I found solution

```
1) npm init  -> and  define package.json
2) npm install cucumber@latest
3) node_modules\.bin\cucumber.js.cmd  <path>\myfeature.feature
```